# Hover on parent shows hidden child

Tags: jquery

In a Wordpress site I have the following code, but hovering over `.insightdesign_text_reveal` does not reveal `.insightdesign_text_reveal_description`.

Help appreciated.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".insightdesign_text_reveal").hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).find(".insightdesign_text_reveal_description").show();
        } function(){
            jQuery(this).find(".insightdesign_text_reveal_description").hide(); 
        };
    });
</script>
<style>
    .insightdesign_text_reveal_description {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="et_pb_module insightdesign_text_reveal insightdesign_text_reveal_0 et_pb_bg_layout_light clearfix ">
    <h3 class="et_pb_module_header">History</h3>
    <div class="insightdesign_text_reveal_description">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.</p>
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_team_member_description -->
</div>
```

Comment: If no required of using js, use css instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only css to do it

```
.insightdesign_text_reveal_description {
    display: none;
}
.et_pb_module_header:hover + .insightdesign_text_reveal_description{
      display: unset;
}
```

Comment: With CSS3, it's best to use `display: unset;` instead of `block`.

Comment: I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362687/hover-on-multiple-parents-shows-hidden-child) where there are multiple parents. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of Syntax error. Try this way.

```js
jQuery(".insightdesign_text_reveal").hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".insightdesign_text_reveal_description").show();
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".insightdesign_text_reveal_description").hide();
});
```

```css
.insightdesign_text_reveal_description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_module insightdesign_text_reveal insightdesign_text_reveal_0 et_pb_bg_layout_light clearfix ">
  <h3 class="et_pb_module_header">History</h3>
  <div class="insightdesign_text_reveal_description">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_team_member_description -->
</div>
```